# Unable to disable Dropbox's autostart in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, startup, dropbox, autostart

### The Problem

I installed `nautilus-dropbox` in Ubuntu 18.04. The app itself works fine, but it does not respect the *Start Dropbox on system startup* option.

- When I start Dropbox manually, it creates a file at `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop`.
- If I issue the command `$ dropbox autostart n` the file is removed.
- If I restart Dropbox the offending file is recreated.

### The Failed Fix

I've tried adding `dropbox autostart n` to `dropbox start -i` in `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`. This results in `Exec=dropbox start -i; dropbox autostart n`.

Now when I start Dropbox **it still** recreates the file in `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` but now the line `Exec=dropbox start -i` appears as `Exec=dropbox start -i; dropbox autostart n`.

(Starting Dropbox via command line also creates the file in `~/.config/autostart/`.)

### The Dumb Solution

Issue a `$ dropbox autostart n` after starting the daemon.

### The Request

Assuming I don't want it to start and then stop during boot, but to remain dead until I wake it up manually via command line or apps menu.

How do I prevent Dropbox from starting during system boot?

### Update (a few months later...)

This issue has been solved by Dropbox with a client update.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hacky, but I've restarted a few times and it seems to be working.

I went to /home/[user]/.config/autostart and found the Dropbox shortcut.  I opened it and changed the command (I wanted to start it using dbus-launch, so that's what I did, but if you don't want to start Dropbox at all, I think you could just delete everything in the Command field).

Then, to prevent Dropbox from overwriting it the next time it starts, I went to the permissions for the shortcut and set it so that Nobody has permission to change content.

So far it seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an odd situation on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.1 where with:

- `dropbox` unlinked
- `thunar-dropbox-plugin` and `nautilus-dropbox` uninstalled
- `~/.dropbox` and `~/.dropbox-dist` deleted

I was still seeing log entries that dropbox was trying to start but couldn't find files.  There were suggestions to clear:

- `~/.cache/` (removed all but wine related)
- `~/.config/autostart/` (remove dropbox related)
- `~/.config/xfce4-session/` (remove all)

But a closer examination of the log mentioned ureadahead so I eventually cleared it by:

- `/var/lib/ureadahead/` (remove *.pack and pack)

With the caches clear, dropbox no longer tries to start which answers the question.  A manual installation of dropbox with:

`cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
./.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-57.4.89/dropbox start -i`

Shouldn't be able to autostart at all and would require something like the second command to manually start it.

For my purposes, I simply wanted to fix XFCE icon corruption so I reinstalled the plugins and used sed to update the global desktop entry.

`sudo apt install thunar-dropbox-plugin nautilus-dropbox
sudo sed -i "s|\(Exec=\)dropbox start -i|\\1dbus-launch dropbox start -i|" /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`